# App Engine Python 2.7 App Works on dev but make Error 500 on production

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm deploying Python 2.7 app to Google App Engine.
The app works on local dev-server but when I try to deploy it the deployment complete successfully but any HTTP request to the app result in error 500, no matter what url I'm using.

In the App Engine logs I see the logging of the 500 response but no clue to what the problem is.

I've also try to deploy the last code that did worked and the result is the same so it doesn't looks like the code changes are the reason.

Any idea how to diagnose this problem?

You can see the [code of the app](https://github.com/ido-ran/SmartAirCondition/tree/master/SmartAirConditionServer).

Comment: A few things would help.  Are you using GAE standard or flexible?  Custom domain or appspot.com domain?  Errors could be in your app.yaml or you webapp2 routes so sharing relevant portions of those would help.  Include the relevant portion of logs as well.

Comment: I'm using standard, no custom domain. I've add link to the app source code.

Comment: Are you logged in as an admin? You have `login: admin` for your wilcard path `url: /.*`. You should be able to see some tracebacks associated with those 500 error logs in the developer console...

Comment: Yes, I am the admin if this app and I see log of the 500 request but no trackback

Comment: In your position, I'd first try cutting my app down to a single handler (commenting out unused methods and imports) to see if I could reproduce the issue with a small test case. If that works, add handlers a group at a time. Local version control is your friend when trying something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ends up being tiny mistake that I've changed the `api_version` from `1` to `2`.

The app.yaml needs to start like this:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
```

In my code it was like this which causes the error:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 2
threadsafe: true
```